# WAMP 3.0.4 & send mail

Tags: php, email, wamp, sendmail

I am trying to configure my WAMP server to send emails via sendmail I have even set the gmail account and everything. Prior to doing this, my wamp server was working fine(green). But now its orange(1 of 2 services working) I am new to using WAMP server so I don't know what the problem is. The problem started when I enabled the ssl_module on Apache

#### php.ini(from WAMP interface)

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from ="admin@wampserver.invalid"

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

#### sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]


smtp_server=stmp.gmail.com



smtp_port=465


smtp_ssl=ssl

default_domain=localhost


error_logfile=error.log


debug_logfile=debug.log


auth_username= myemail@gmail.com
auth_password= mypassword

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

force_sender=


force_recipient=



hostname=localhost
```

Comment: Orange means your web server isn't starting up, probably due to an error in your configuration. Please provide the startup log for your server.

Comment: @Chris is it the apache error log or access log?...sorry im new to WAMP

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different smtp's in php.ini and sendmail.ini. Also port numbers must be the same.

What if you disable ssl module again?

Also check if you are using a same port number for a different service. As you know, you can't use the same port number for two different services.

Comment: WAMP doesn't allow me to disable ssl module

Comment: I use XAMPP, its much better and I have all those features working. https://www.apachefriends.org/